# Attach event to plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using `Ckeditor` with default `Source` plugin:

When i initialize the editor, i set some css styles to the editor based on some parameters i have.

The problem is that, when i go into Source mode, then back to editor again, the editor gets re-created and loses my css styles.

Is possible to attach a callback to `Source` plugin, so i can re-set the styles when the editor gets re-created?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`editor#mode`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-mode) event to bypass that limitation:

```
editor.on( 'mode', function() {
    // Note: The event is also fired when editor is created.
    if ( editor.mode == 'wysiwyg' ) {
        // Do the style magic when editor switches to WYSIWYG!
    }
} );
```

Comment: Works perfect! I also found `Sourcedialog` plugin which opens the source code in a popup, so the editor doesn't gets re-created